# trying open folder with intent

Tags: java, android, android-storage

i want to open a specific folder from menu drawer in android app but when i run the app it open recent files folder.

this is my code

```html
if (id == R.id.action_downloaded) {
            if (PermissionUtilities.isPermissionGranted(mActivity, PermissionUtilities.SD_READ_WRITE_PERMISSIONS, PermissionUtilities.REQUEST_READ_WRITE_STORAGE_DOWNLOAD)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + myfolder + "/");
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/*");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), 1000);
            }
```

Comment: "how to do that?" -- generally, you don't. There has never been official support for this.

Answer (score 0):

Put as extra INITIAL_URI on your intent an uri the user choosed before with ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: i can't find class INITIAL_URI